# Unable to validate the file using WinSCP script before uploading to SFTP

Tags: ssis, winscp

I am new to WinSCP and trying to upload file after validation using WinSCP and SSIS job. SSIS job will call this script and this script needs to validate and upload the file.

The script is as:

```
open Sftp://Username:password@ftplogin
option transfer binary
put -delete C:\Temp\testingfile.xlsx /Destinationfolder/
close 
exit
```

I am trying to validate the file before uploading. Validations are as:if file exist and to get the record count of excel file.
Can anyone help me on this please.

Comment: *"to get the record count of excel file"* - What does that mean? - Why do you think that WinSCP should be even able to do this for you? You should do "validations" in SSIS flow before even running WinSCP.

Comment: i don't think that this is the right way to do validation!!

Answer (score 2):

For using WinSCP with SSIS I'd recommend using a script task.  To learn more about this visit their [website](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library), which also includes the link to download it.  While WinSCP does offers ways of verifying file attributes I've found [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) to be more beneficial, thus the following uses the `Where` method to do the filtering.  The example below verifies the beginning of the file name with the `String.StartsWith` method on the `Name` property, which only includes the file name, not full path.  The extension is confirmed with the `String.EndsWith` method.  If both of these return true, the file path is placed in a list and transferred using the `Session.GetFiles` method.  Afterwards an excel `Workbook` is defined for the file, with the `Count` property obtaining the number of rows in the spreadsheet, with the first spreadsheet used in this example.  You may also need to load to WinSCP assembly.  If you do encounter this error related to this, you can load it using the `ResolveEventHandler` delegate as follows.  The path sent to the `LoadFile` method will be where the `WinSCPnet` dll was downloaded.

```
using System.Linq;
using WinSCP;
using System.Collections.Generic;

//load WinSCPnet.dll  
 static ScriptMain()
 {
     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
 }
 static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
 {
     if (args.Name.ToUpper().Contains("WINSCPNET"))
     {
         string path = @"C:\WinSCP Download Path\";
         return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "WinSCPnet.dll"));
     }
     return null;  
 }

    public void Main()
    {
 SessionOptions sessOpt = new SessionOptions
   {
     Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
     HostName = "SFTPsite.com",
     UserName = "user",
     Password = "password",
     SshHostKeyFingerprint = "Your SshHostKeyFingerprint"
   };

 using (Session session = new Session())
 {
   session.Open(sessOpt);

   TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
   transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;
   int excelRecordCount = 0;

   string remotePath = @"/SFTP Folder/";
   string localPath = @"C:\Local Folder\";
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application exlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

   RemoteDirectoryInfo rdi = session.ListDirectory(remotePath);

   //verify file existence by matching beginning of name and extension
   List<string> fileList = rdi.Files.Where(file => (file.Name.StartsWith("Prefix"))
   && (file.FullName.EndsWith(".xlsx"))).Select(file => file.FullName).ToList();

   foreach (string s in fileList)
   {
       //transfer matching files
       session.GetFiles(s, localPath, false, transferOptions);

       //get excel file name by combining local path and name of transferred file 
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook exlWorkbook = exlApp.Workbooks.Open(localPath + 
           s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(@"/"), s.Length - s.LastIndexOf(@"/")));
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet exlWorksheet = exlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range excelRange = exlWorksheet.UsedRange;

       //get row count
       excelRecordCount = excelRange.Rows.Count;
   }
    //close excel file
    exlWorkbook = null;
    xlApp.Quit();
    xlApp = null;
 }
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use WinSCP to move files after validation with SSIS, then you can use a script task component to do this. The nice thing here is that WinSCP already provides the code for how to do this in a script task (see reference below). Note: you will need to download the WinSCPNet.dll assembly and install it to the Global Assembly Cache (GAC).

**References:**

SSIS Script Task setup: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ssis#ssis_ssdt_task

Script Task C# Code: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_ssis

WinSCPNet.dll Assembly: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install